# Installed a package and now my mouse and keyboard don't work :(

Tags: xorg, input

Recently, I installed virtualbox-guest-x11, and the dependencies: xserver-xorg-core, and xorg-video-abi20.

When I typed "sudo reboot" my laptop rebooted to loging, but my mouse and keyboard do not respond at all! Any ideas what could have caused this?? I have no way to do anything anymore!

I have tried booking to recovery mode, and when dropping to the command line and trying to remove these packages gives me errors, and so does trying to enter networking mode. I feel pretty stuck!

Do I just need to wipe the entire hardrive and reinstall??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the errors mention `Read-only file system`? If so, you could try running `mount -o remount,rw /` before removing `virtualbox-guest-x11`.

Comment: Did you install the guest package on your actual (host) pc?  It's meant to be installed on the virtual machine.